# In Javamail Attachment is not displaying

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

In Javamail Attachment is not displaying

I tried to send a mail with attachment
It sending and received  But  in received mail attachment is not displaying not display
attachment is blank and 
Here the code is:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
javaMailSender.setPort(587);
javaMailSender.setUsername("*******@gmail.com");
javaMailSender.setPassword("*********");
Properties props = ((JavaMailSenderImpl) javaMailSender).getJavaMailProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.mime.multipart.allowempty", "true");
javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
return javaMailSender;
}
{
message.setSubject(mailServiceDTO.getSubject());
message.setText(mailServiceDTO.getSubject(), "text/html");
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(mailServiceDTO.getSubject(), "text/html");
for (EmailAttachment attachment : mailServiceDTO.getAttachments()) {
message.addAttachment(attachment.getAttachmentName(), new ByteArrayResource(attachment.getAttachmentContent().getBytes()));
}
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
mimeMessage.setContent(mp);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

Comment: What does the MIME content of the received message look like?  Can you use "view source" or some similar function in the mailer you're using to read the message so we can see what is actually getting sent and whether it's structured properly to be displayed?

Comment: What happens if you move the MimeMessage.setContent line and the 2 lines above it to before the addAttachment loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MimeMessageHelper in spring mail.

Example

```
        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

    MimeMessageHelper mailMessage = null;
    List<PathSource> pathSourceList = request.getMailAttachList();
    if (pathSourceList != null && pathSourceList.size() > 0)
        mailMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
    else
        mailMessage = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, false);
    // .... 
    if (pathSourceList != null && pathSourceList.size() > 0) {
        for (PathSource filepath : pathSourceList) {
            ByteArrayResource stream = new ByteArrayResource(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(
                    filepath.getData()));
            mailMessage.addAttachment(filepath.getFileName(), stream);
        }
    }
    try {
        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage.getMimeMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("server info {}", serverModel.toString());
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Multiple attachments..

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {

  final String fromEmail = ""; // requires valid gmail id
  final String password = "";// correct password for gmail id
  final String toEmail = ""; // can be any 
  System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // SMTP Host
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // TLS Port
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // enable authentication
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // enable STARTTLS

  Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
   // override the getPasswordAuthentication method
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
   }
  };

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
  System.out.println("Session created");
  

  sendAttachmentEmail(session,fromEmail, toEmail,"SSLEmail Testing Subject with Attachment", "SSLEmail Testing Body with Attachment");

 

 }


public static void sendAttachmentEmail(Session session,String fromEmail, String toEmail, String subject, String body){
 try{
         MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
      msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
      msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
       
      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));

      msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));

      msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

      msg.setSentDate(new Date());

      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
       
         // Create the message body part
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Fill the message
         messageBodyPart.setText(body);
         
         // Create a multipart message for attachment
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

         // Set text message part
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         
         String filename1 = "C:\\TraingWorkspace\\Training\\logs\\DailyLog.zip";
         addAttachment(multipart, filename1);
         String filename2 = "C:\\TraingWorkspace\\Training\\logs\\DailyLog.log";
         addAttachment(multipart, filename2);

         // Send the complete message parts
         msg.setContent(multipart);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(msg);
         System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully with attachment!!");
      }catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

private static void addAttachment(Multipart multipart, String filename) throws MessagingException
{
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();        
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}
```